# Unmarshalling to an array or arrayList in Java

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling, unmarshalling

I'm trying to populate an arraylist after unmarshalling and xml file, but it unmarshals to an object, how can I get each individual item out and copied to something else like an array?

I can marshal and unmarshal, but can't get nothing out of the object except some adress of memory etc..

here is the unmarshalling

```
try {

            File file = new File("xmlFiles/ipAdresses.xml");
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(IpAdressXmlHandler.class);

            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            IpAdressXmlHandler xmlList = (IpAdressXmlHandler) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
            System.out.println(xmlList);

          } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
```

how do I get xmlList as an array? or how do I get everything out?

IpAdressXmlHandler class:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class IpAdressXmlHandler {


private String ipAdress;

@XmlElement
public String getIpAdress() {
    return ipAdress;
}


public void setIpAdress(String ipAdress) {
    this.ipAdress = ipAdress;
}
```

UPDATE: xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ipAdressXmlHandler>
<ipAdress>localhost</ipAdress>
</ipAdressXmlHandler>
```

there more than one ip address later and I need them in an array or arraylist

Comment: You should probably provide us with the XML files you're unmarshalling from!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class IpAdressXmlHandler {

@XmlElement(name="ipAdress")
private String ipAdress;

public String getIpAdress() {
    return ipAdress;
}


public void setIpAdress(String ipAdress) {
    this.ipAdress = ipAdress;
}

@XmlRootElement(name="ipAdressXmlHandler")
public class IpAdressListXmlHandler {

@XmlElement(name="ipAdress")
private List<IpAdressXmlHandler> ipAdress;


public List<IpAdressXmlHandler> getIpAdressList() {
    return ipAdress;
}


public void setIpAdressList(List<IpAdressXmlHandler> ipAdress) {
    this.ipAdress = ipAdress;
}
```

Use IpAdressListXmlHandler class for unmarshelling..

Comment: do I have to define IpAdressListXmlHandler? it doesn't compile

Comment: error com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 2 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions

Comment: i just write a code u check it..this is proper way to do it..check [link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JAXB/article.html)

Comment: It returns IpAdressListXmlHandler object.then use getIpAdressList() get ipaddress.

Comment: I'm getting 2 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions

Comment: @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD) use this annotation in your java classes.after @XmlRootElement. try latest edit.

Comment: 1 count of illegal annotation

Comment: getting close, thank you so much, don't know what that 1 annotation is

Answer (score 1):

`IpAdressXmlHandler` is the entity representing your `XML`, as long as in the `XSD` definition of this `XML` there is only one tag allowed you will never get a `List`.

**SOLUTION**
Your `XSD` definition must have `maxoccurs="otbounded"` or similar to allow various `<IpAdressXmlHandler>` tags. Once done, `JaxB` will auto generate the  `getter` returning a `List<IpAdressXmlHandler>`.

**UPDATE**
IMO I would create a [`XSD`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/) file according your xml specs... put it into your workspace and `Right click > Generate > JaxB classes`.

If you want to get a `List<IpAdressXmlHandler>` you must create a wrapper for your xml that contains a `List<IpAdressXmlHandler>` and returns it, but you must **unmarshall the wrapper, not `IpAdressXmlHandler`**.

Something like:

```
class IpWrapper{

    private List<IpAdressXmlHandler> ipList;   

    @XmlElement
    public List<IpAdressXmlHandler> getIpAdressXmlHandler() {
        return ipList;
    }
}
```

And:

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(IpWrapper.class);
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
```

Comment: I'm a bit of a newbie, not sure what you mean. What should I change? been on this for a long time. thank you so much

Comment: the `IpAdressXmlHandler` is auto generated by JaxB right? you must change definition of the file that makes `JaxB` create this class, normally is a `XSD` file that defines the allowed tags and content of the `XML`

Comment: IpAdressXmlHandler is the class I created, I marshal it into the xml file, check my update